# First depiction of a quadruped robot-vehicle?

Tags: first-appearance, science-fiction, cinema-history

Episode 2 of [Nadia: The Secret of Blue Water (1990)](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0096591/) shows the baddies pursuing the main characters in a convertible vehicle, a submarine/ship that becomes a quadruped robot at some point of the episode.

[screenshot with Grandis Granva](https://i.ibb.co/DK5Q0QC/Screenshot-20190608-140245-You-Tube.jpg)

This reminded me of later appearances such as the tank towards the end of [Ghost in the Shell (1995)](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0113568/), or in other media the "Metal Gear" weapons.

What is the inspiration for giant quadruped vehicle robots?

Comment: Are you interested in animation only? If not, I'll thow in [these ones](https://youtu.be/3acC49W3yQk?t=33).

Comment: Those work too, did not think about it

Comment: Not quadruped, but in Greek Mythology Hephaestus built tripods that would walk to and from Mount Olympus...